# How to mount on /mnt/ as non-root with gcsfuse

Tags: linux, gcsfuse

**Introduction**

I am using gcsfuse to mount my Cloud Storage bucket as a filesystem in my Linux instance hosted on GCE.

Following the documentation from gcsfuse, it recommends to not use "root" to mount it, as the user who mounts the filesystem will be the owner. Hence, you won't be able to write or read objects as  a normal user.

The mounting point that I intend to use is /mnt/, but it requires system administrator permissions and I would like to use a [non-root user](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#ownership).

**Question**

How could I circumvent this limitation? I followed this [other question](https://gcsfuse%20automount%20on%20a%20non%20root%20user), but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, you will be able to mount the bucket inside /mnt folder without changing the ownership of /mnt dir.

Instead you can try by creating a folder inside /mnt/ and change the ownership of that folder, and then try mounting the bucket using gcsfuse.

Steps would be:

1. cd /mnt
2. sudo mkdir mount_bucket
3. sudo chown : mount_bucket
4. Mount the /mnt/mount_bucket with non-root user.